# How to switch from LocalDB instance to SQL Express?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, code-first, sql-server-express

I created an SQL Express database and built an Entity Data Model off of it using the wizard, then used the Repository Pattern to generate a helper class that does my querying for me.

Unfortunately what I didn't realize is that Code First creates a localdb copy and basically ALL my add/removes now go to this ethereal location that I can't find so I can't run queries off the data in SQL Express. Now I know the data is being saved because I'm able to check the underlying model through breakpoints and queries during page load with using(Context = new Context()) { /*query stuff*/ }, but I don't know how to switch from the underlying model back to my SqlExpress instance.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDb is just another sql server database, which is started by Visual Studio. It's data most of the time are in %USER% directory and you can open it with Sql Server Management Studio. To switch your project to your sql express instance, you need to change the connection string, that's all.

Comment: I've seen the connection string you're talking about (I think), but I was hoping to find a way to persist the two separate connection strings so I could switch back to the code first version if I found it to be more useful. I suppose I could create a backup but that seems silly.

Comment: Code First does not create a localdb copy. Context you created either by db -> model -> code, either by hand, calls its base constructor with the name of connection string to use. There is possibility your wizard created another connection string ;) If you have two contexts using two different connection strings (and two databases), then that's just overcomplicating stuff. I'd recommend sticking with one database at once ;)